# Sorting by a list column in a Search Kit

Tags: searchkit

I have contacts that can be related to other by RelationshipA or RelationshipB.  I created a query in Search Kit to return the primary contact and the related contacts and everyone's email address.

I grouped by the primary contact's ContactID and sorted by sortname.  For the information about the related contacts I set their fields in field transformation as list.

All works fine, except.  The resulting data always lists the related contacts as RelationshipB followed by RelationshipA. I added a table and then added Relationship type to the sort fields set to descending.  This makes no difference.

My question:  How can a sort the related contacts in the order I need (by relationship type) within each contact?

Comment: Order by contact, relationship type?

Comment: This question is a bit hard to follow.  Could you export your SearchKit query and edit your question to include it?